# Vim SuperTab: How to specify suggestions source

Tags: vim, plugins, tags, supertab

I have been playing around with the Vim-plugin "SuperTab" for a while, and it has become nearly unusable to me due to the enormous delay following the press of the [Tab] key. This is due to **SuperTab using tag files as a source for result suggestions.**

This is problematic to me since the tag file for our codebase at work is quite big (37mb~), so depending on the situation, hitting [Tab] sometimes invokes a query that may take 15+ seconds to complete. Not quite a time-saver.

Is there any way to tell SuperTab to ignore my tags variable, because I would very much like to keep using it for other plugins like taglist.vim, or optionally, an alternative to SuperTab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supertab uses the *default completion*; its sources can be configured via the `'complete'` option. A

```
:set complete-=t
```

should remove the tag completion; other plugins won't be affected, but the default insert mode completion (`<C-n>` / `<C-p>`) is. Alternatively, you could reconfigure Supertab to use another completion, e.g. the buffer-local one (`<C-x><C-n>`).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Props!